# Is there a living styleguide generator for Angular 2, much like styleguidist for React?

Tags: javascript, angular

For React, there exist a couple of *living* styleguide generators, like styleguidist, that take components, sass and some extra editable text and automatically generate a styleguide for a particular app out of this, depending on where the styleguide task is inserted into the build process, with every repeat of that process. Does anything similar exist for Angular 2+?

**Caveat**: I do not mean a *coding styleguide*, but a *living* styleguide that pretty much automatically documents layout (sass/css)styles, fonts, icons, colours, font sizes, and components with their parameters, amongst others. Those things happen to be called styleguides too, sorry about that, but I did not invent the name.

Comment: oK, whoever voted this down for lack of research should get voted down for lack of reading comprehension. I tried to keep the description text short, but I'll expand a bit...

Comment: This github page contains information about a variety of living styleguide generators, also in JS. As far as I can see, none address Angular 2 specifically and most are centered around CSS and preprocessors, not components: https://github.com/davidhund/styleguide-generators#user-content-css-parsing-css-source

Tapestry has "Angular" listed as a keyword, but the demo does not even work in Chrome 57.0 on the Mac. However, styleguidist is listed... This is a very long list, however, so I will have to see if there is something useful or that can be adapted...

Comment: Have you found any good solutions in the time since you asked this question?

Comment: nope, unfortunately, I haven't

Comment: It seems like Compodoc might be the ticket: https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc but I haven't had a chance to try it out yet

Comment: Compodoc is great but it's more about documenting components and the methods inside of them than the kind of styleguide content that you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

UI-jar is a drop in module that automatically create a living style guide based on the test you write for your components in Angular (2.x and above). A beta is available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-jar

With UI-jar it's also possible to develop your components isolated, without the need of the rest of your app.

You also get documentation about your components.

Comment: thanks, will have a look at that. First I was like "UI.jar? what the heck?", but then I saw it was a dash;-)

Comment: First look is promising. Thanks for that, i'll tray to spend a while on this and give you feedback.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions. There is a example app created with Angular CLI available at https://github.com/ui-jar/ui-jar/tree/master/examples/example-app-with-angular-cli

Comment: I saw example. I miss most important feature - see code used to produce preview.

Comment: Allright, I'm actually working om that :) it's going to be available soon.

Comment: latest release 2018, it seems abandoned :'(

Answer (score 5):

[Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) is also a good solution, but you also need to write code to define your different scenarios. Storybook has been originally developed for React but is now also compatible with Angular.

Comment: hah, coincidentally I just had a job interview where storybook came up. Haven't used it yet, though, but it looks like I might give it a spin soon.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [Angular Playground](http://www.angularplayground.it/).  You have to write some code to define the scenarios that you want it to provide, but I've been using it on my projects and I like it.

If you want automatic UI component documentation, I'd go with [Compodoc](https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc) like yogibimbi mentioned in their comment.

It seems like there is a missing tool in the ecosystem that provides something like a combination of these two utilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KSS](http://warpspire.com/kss/). It's really simple:
You have to write some code to describe your CSS class, thing like that:

```
// Primary Button
//
// Use this class for the primary call to action button.
// Typically you'll want to use either a `<button>` or an `<a>` element.
//
// Markup:
// <button class="btn--primary">Click Me</button>
// <a href="#" class="btn btn--primary">Click Me</a>
//
// Styleguide Components.Buttons.Primary

.btn--primary {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: aqua;
  color: red;
}
```

and to make it easy to use,i define a command in package.json:

```
 "kss": "ng build --extract-css true && kss --source ./ --destination styleguide --css ../dist/styles.bundle.css"
```

and then you just run :

```
npm run kss
```

Actually this command make a new folder named "styleguide", beside src folder in your angular project and all thing is ready and you just open "/styleguide/index.html" and Enjoy. I hope it help you.